# how to upload files

Tags: asp.net, upload

How to upload files from ASP.NET web application to any web server(linux)..

Comment: Could you please clarify? Do you mean to upload a file from a browser to your server ASP.NET application (running in a linux server), or do you want to upload a file from one server (running your ASP.NET application) to another server (running...someting, under linux)?

Comment: i want to upload a file from one server (running my ASP.NET application) to another server running under linux..

Comment: this complete nodejs code example might be the answer of your question (including server and client-side code): https://github.com/malikasinger1/upload-file-nodejs

Answer (score 1):

Take these steps as a general guideline:

- include an ASP.NET server control for the user to upload the file
- have its [`SaveAs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx) path be a [UNC path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNC_path#Uniform_Naming_Convention) to a share on the remote server.

Here's more on the [FileUpload ASP.NET Server Control at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx).

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(@"\\server2\SomeShare\" + FileUpload1.FileName);
}
```

**If** you wanted the files to be saved first on your ASP.NET box:

- save the file locally (something like `c:\uploads\temp` or what-have-you
- at some interval or your chose event, move all files in that temp dir from server1 to server2.
- use [`System.IO.File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx)

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\uploads\temp");

foreach (string s in files)
{
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
    string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
    System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Linux server in question exposes an FTP service, then [here's a tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/FtpClient.aspx) for accessing that in .NET.  If FTP is not an option, then please specify what service the Linux server is exposing for file upload (Samba, NFS, etc.).

Comment: @kenom: The code in that tutorial can be translated to C# very easily, it doesn't seem to be using any VB-only constructs that I've noticed.  If you need, you can probably find a VB .NET to C# convertor online.  If not, just compile it in VB and use Reflector to disassemble it into C# if you must.  But, honestly, that's all overkill.  The code isn't complex.